# tacotron2の環境構築が終わらない（Google colab 環境）

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory, cuda

春先からtacotron2で音声合成をしようと試みているのですが、
tacotron2に求められているモジュールのバージョンが古いために、
Google colabでほぼ一から環境構築をしている状態です。
最終的にはtacotron2を動かせる状態まで持っていきたいのですが、
cudnnのテストに突っかかっています。
素人かつ中学生でアマなのでとても困ってます。
どのようにすればひとまずはcudnnのテストを成功させれるでしょうか？

参考にしているサイト

[NVIDIA/tacotron2 で日本語の音声合成を試す (1) - 事始め](https://note.com/npaka/n/n2a91c3ca9f34)
[NVIDIA/tacotron2 で日本語の音声合成を試す (2) - JSUTで学習](https://note.com/npaka/n/n2eec2558ede1)
[tacotron2を使って音声合成をローカル環境で試した時の備忘録](https://trend-tracer.com/python-tacotron2/)

上から２つ目の方のJSUTを使って学習させようとしています。

初めて質問するのと国語力ないので読みにくいかと思いますが詳しい方答えていただけるとありがたいです。

ソースコード

```
#python3.6に変更
!sudo apt install python3.6
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!python --version

#Google Driveへマウント
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')

#pip再インストール　→pip installしようとしたらpipが壊れていたため
!sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip
!curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
!sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.6-distutils
!python3 get-pip.py --user
!python3 get-pip.py --user

#tensorflowのインストール
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5

#pytorch1.2でしたのインストール
!pip install torch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0

#依存パッケージのインストール - requirement.txt
!pip --default-timeout=1000 install -r /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/tacotron2/requirements.txt --user

#CUDAの再インストール - CUDA-10.0
!sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*

!sudo dpkg -i /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/7fa2af80.pub
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt install --no-install-recommends cuda-10-0

!apt --fix-broken install

#環境変数の設定
import os
p = os.getenv('PATH')
ld = os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
os.environ['PATH'] = f"/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:{p}"
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = f"/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:{ld}"

#gcc7.3.0のインストール
!tar -zxf /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz

#%cd /content/gcc-7.3.0/
!./contrib/download_prerequisites
%cd ..
!mkdir objdir
%cd objdir
!$PWD/../gcc-7.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib
!make -j`nproc`
!make install

#gccのバージョンダウン
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/gcc-7.3.0/bin/gcc 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/gcc-7.3.0/bin/g++
!sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
!gcc --version

#cudnnのインストール
%cd /content
!sudo dpkg -i /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/libcudnn7_7.4.2.24-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/libcudnn7-dev_7.4.2.24-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/libcudnn7-doc_7.4.2.24-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb

!sudo apt upgrade -y

!tar -zxf /content/drive/MyDrive/音声合成/cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.4.2.24.tgz
!sudo cp -a cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/
!sudo cp -a -P cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
!sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*

#cudnnのテスト
!cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7/ ./
%cd /content/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN/

!make clean && make
!./mnistCUDNN

#cudnnのテスト 以下で出てきたエラーコード

/content/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN
rm -rf *o
rm -rf mnistCUDNN
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include  -m64    -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=compute_53 -o fp16_dev.o -c fp16_dev.cu
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/local/cuda/include/crt/host_config.h:129:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 7 are not supported!
  129 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 7 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:212: fp16_dev.o] Error 1
/bin/bash: ./mnistCUDNN: No such file or directory
```